# Protocol not being executed

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I'm trying to implement light and dark theme throughout the entire app. My problem is that it's not working properly. I have a `ContainerVC` that contains 2 `ContainerViews` - `SidebarMenuVC` and `DashboardVC`. `SidebarMenuVC` is offset so initially, the user is being displayed `DashboardVC`.

The `ContainerVC` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` and there's a hamburger type menu. When the user taps on that menu button, `SidebarMenuVC` is being displayed. It all works just fine.

`SidebarMenuVC` contains an image that is responsible for changing the theme of the app. When the user taps on the image it goes from light to dark or vice versa. The moment of tap changes the theme of `SidebarMenuVC` but when you hide the menu (via swipe), `DashboardVC`'s theme is not being applied. I tried to do that with `protocol` but I think I'm not doing it correctly (well, its not working so I KNOW i've messed up somehow).

```
protocol ReloadTheme {
    func reload()
}

class ContainerVC: UIViewController, SidebarDelegate {

    var delegateReloadTheme: ReloadTheme?
    func hideMenu() {
        sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint.constant = -300
        applyTheme()
        animateConstraint()
        delegateReloadTheme?.reload() // when I put a breakpoint here, it shows it's nil
    }
}

extension DashboardVC : ReloadTheme {
    func reload() {
        applyTheme()
    }
}
```

So, the big picture is: when the user swipe right to `hideMenu()` (which is in `ContainerVC`, it somehow needs to access `DashboardVC` and call `applyTheme()`

Protocols/Delegates always confuse me, so a little bit of help is welcome.

Okay, so as requested, here's how the `sidebarMenu` is connected:

```
protocol SideBarDelegate: class {
      func showMenu()
      func hideMenu()
}
class DashboardVC: UIViewController {
   static weak var delegateSideBar: SideBarDelegate?

    @IBAction func sideMenuButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
         Dashboard.delegateSideBar?.showMenu()
     }    
}
```

And then in the `ContainerVC` :

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DashboardVC.delegateSideBar = self
  }

 func hideMenu() {
    sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint.constant = -300
    dimView.isHidden = true
    applyTheme()
    animateConstraint()
  //  delegateReloadTheme?.reloadTheme()
}
func showMenu() {
    sideBarMenuLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
    dimView.isHidden = false
    applyTheme()
    animateConstraint()
}

func animateConstraint() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
}
```

And that's how the swipe menu works and it's connected.

Comment: For this to work the property `delegateReloadTheme` has to be assigned an object that implements the protocol `ReloadTheme` somwhere in your code. Is this the case?

Comment: No, but I'm aware it needs to be done and I just dont know where to do that ...

Comment: @Dani It shows up nil when you put a breakpoint there because your delegate is an optional you never set.

Comment: Try setting your delegate in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Dani take a look at the answer. Also, please provide code that connects DashboardVC and side menu somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your delegate somewhere - it is optional type.

For instance, in `viewDidLoad` you can say `item.delegateReloadTheme = self`.

You need to show more code regarding `DashboardVC`.

Basically, when you create delegate, you are creating interface for the work that needs to be delegated, and you delegate it to other class. Because you can implement delegate almost anywhere in the code, you need to tell who is in charge of the implementing that delegate(interface).

for example:

```
protocol RefresherDelegate {
    func refreshUI()
}
```

Here we define what function(s) will be delegate.

```
class MyView : UIView {
    var delegate: RefresherDelegate?
}
```

Here, we create variable that will hold object that actually confroms `RefresherDelegate`.

```
class MyObject : RefresherDelegate {
    var myView = MyView()
```

Here you say that `MyObject` will implement `RefresherDelegate` and create simple MyView instance (won't show on UI, just simple example)

```
func assignDelegate() {
    myView.delegate = self
}
```

This is crucial part - assign delegate to implementation of it - in this case `MyObject`.

After `assignDelegate()`, when you actually call `refreshUI()` it will be get called in `MyObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've read so many really, watched videos, still dont understand it completely. I've added the code from `DashboardVC` that's connecting the sidebar menu

Comment: Let me get it right - show/hide works fine but changing theme doesn't?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The menu works just fine, if the user changes the theme, its not being implemented to `DashboardVC` accordingly. What's tripping me here is that there are 3 `UIViewControllers` involved. The `ContainerVC` that's responsible for the sidebar menu, the `SidebarMenuVC` that's responsible for changing the theme and then the third one - `DashboardVC` where the theme is not being changed (unless you switch the view, but that's because I call `applyTheme()` in `viewWillAppear()` in the same view controller)

Comment: okay, you still need delegate you declared in the original post - now it is only matter of connection between SideControl -> Dashboard. you can use the same way you did for dashboard VC: static weak var delegateReloadTheme: ReloadTheme? (even it is bad way to go, but since I don't know almost anything about layouting views, this will work) and then, on call you show you can assign it there.

Comment: @IBAction func sideMenuButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { ContainerVC. delegateReloadTheme = self
         Dashboard.delegateSideBar?.showMenu()
     }